# After importing pandasql as sqldf , getting 'module' object is not callable error

Tags: pandasql

I imported the below :

```
import pandasql as sqldf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandasql import load_meat, load_births

pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())**


meat=load_meat()
```

when I write a query `pysqldf("SELECT * FROM meat LIMIT 5;")`

It gives :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-d1c81773e718> in <module>()
----> 1 pysqldf("SELECT * FROM meat LIMIT 5;")

<ipython-input-57-ad9f322e1336> in <lambda>(q)
      1 import pandasql as sqldf
----> 2 pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import numpy as np
      5 from pandasql import load_meat, load_births

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

[image]

Comment: >TypeError: 'module' object is not callable   
Looks to me like you need to make sure, that you call the function from `pandasql` instead of calling the name of the module. My python is rusty, but it seems to me that `import pandasql as sqldf` just renames the `pandasql` module to `sqldf`.

Comment: got it!. thank you so much , that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the pandasql documentation and you need to import the `sqldf` function from pandasql instead of renaming it.

Replace your line `import pandasql as sqldf` with `from pandasqlf import sqldf`.